# Nuget cache in linux

Tags: asp.net, nuget, asp.net-core

I am testing Asp.net 5 (vnext) in Linux Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and I would like to know where is located Nuget cache to properly set local repository in Nuget.Config.
Anyone know?

Answer (score 4):

> The global-packages folder is where NuGet installs any downloaded
>   package. Each package is fully expanded into a subfolder that matches
>   the package identifier and version number. Projects using the
>   PackageReference format always use packages directly from this folder.
>   When using the `packages.config`, packages are installed to the
>   global-packages folder, then copied into the project's packages
>   folder.
>
> - Windows: `%userprofile%\.nuget\packages`
> - Mac/Linux: `~/.nuget/packages`

You can also view global-packages location using below command

```
dotnet nuget locals global-packages --list
```

Typical output (Mac/Linux; "user1" is the current username):

```
info : global-packages: /home/user1/.nuget/packages/
```

For all folders used by NuGet to manages packages and package information use below command

```
dotnet nuget locals all --list
```

[For more details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders#clearing-local-folders)

Comment: The first command only returned the locals for me, but the last command worked perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

NuGet cache is typically located in `~/.local/share/NuGet/Cache` while dnu cache is located in `~/.local/share/dnu/cache`.

Comment: is there a way to change this?